# InputProps min and max not being enforced

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following Form:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      //Make a network call somewhere
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("submitted");
  }
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <TextField
                InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 5, max: 11 } }}
                onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                required
              />

              <Button
                type="submit"
              >
                Submit
              </Button>
            </form>
```

However, I am able to submit the form if the number of characters is less than five or even more than 11. How do I enforce the min/max values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work...

```
...
<TextField
    inputProps={{ min: 5, max: 11, type:"number" }}
    onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
    required
/>
...
```

It is clearly mentioned in the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api), you have to use `inputProps` for native input attribute, small `i`
[image]

Comment: Doesn't work. Same thing....allows me to submit the form anyways

Comment: try to add type attribute `type:" number"` along with min and max

Answer (score 2):

Attributes max and min works on inputs of number type. So you need to set input type to number, in addition to inputProps being and object of attributes.

```
 <TextField
    inputProps={{ min: 5, max: 11, type: "number" }}
    onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
    required
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is `minlength` and `maxlength`:

```
<TextField
  id="standard-required"
  label="Required"
  inputProps={{
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 11,
    pattern: ".{5,11}", // if you have to support IE11
    title: "5 to 11 characters"
  }}
/>
```

I would suggest you to test on different browsers for the support of these attributes.